# Decoding payload msg going through lorawan multitech conduit gateway

Tags: android, json, mqtt, lora

I managed to get a node to communicate to an android app. The message goes from the node to the gateway. Using node-red the gateway publishes the message to an mqtt broker and I subscribe to the right topic to receive that message on my android app.

Only problem I have now is that I never realized that the msg was encoded and I'm quite lost now. I receive an array of bytes on the app side and I'm not sure what is the next step I have to take to be able to read that message.

[image: This is the kind of payload I'm getting]

[image: Debug output for received message]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you update the questions with some examples of the data so we know what we are working with

Answer (score 0):

You are actually receiving bytes from Node-Red. You could either convert the received bytes into String on your Android or modify your lora input node's data type from Bytes to UTF-8.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there is a simple way to convert either bytes or UTF-8 to a string on android? Or maybe, is there a way to do that on node-red directly? Thanks a lot for the answer, you're saving me again!

Comment: Welcome! It would be great if you could post some examples of the data you received in Android.

Comment: I added an example of the payload I'm receiving in the question.

Comment: Have you tried to modify the lora node in your Node-Red?

Comment: Yes, it is set to UTF-8 currently.

Comment: Could you add a debug node to your lora node and post the debug result in your Node-Red?

Comment: Sure! I added it to the question.

Comment: It looks like your device is not sending string properly to Conduit. Your mqtt and Android are working fine. Please make sure if your device is 1) sending string and 2) using LoRaWAN encode the payload properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function to decode it:

```
    var x = Buffer.from(msg.payload.raw,"base64").toString()
    msg.Decrypted = parseFloat(x)
    return msg;
```

In this Instructable i explained how to decode Lora messages in node red
https://www.instructables.com/id/Lora-Temperature-Dashboard/

Answer (score 0):

On a MultiTech Conduit, the message is base64 encoded by the internals of the MTC, then published to the internal mqtt broker at lora//up, so you need to base64 decode it, then do whatever you need to with it. You can use the built in mosquitto applications to subscribe to this topic, or any other mqtt client (paho libraries, etc)